# How to use the serial port to send information from kinect to arduino?

Tags: c#, serialization, arduino, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have fiddled around with the Kinect SDK and arduino, and I have looked around the web to find a way to pass information from the Kinect to the arduino.  I'm only trying to pass some very simple information (i.e. if the kinect recognizes a hand gesture, the arduino do this) and I have found people talking about using the serial port to do this.  I looked at the documentations and people's code, but I'm very new to C# and don't really understand how the serial port works.  I have the Kinect for Windows v1 and am trying to pass information to a botboarduino.  If someone can explain how to set up the serial ports that would be greatly appreciated!

PS. I have been working in Visual Studio 2015 community for the Kinect and in the Arduino IDE for the arduino.

Comment: You can't connect Kinect to an Arduino.  A PC needs to sit in between.  That runs a program that receives Kinect notifications and uses a serial port to let the Arduino know.

Comment: Hey thanks Hans.  I apologize beforehand for not being clear in my question.  I connect both onto my Windows 8 PC and have been working on the Kinect in the Visual Studios 2015 IDE and arduino in the arduino IDE

Comment: Consider using an open source library, e.g. https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino. Or dive into Microsoft IOT (https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot).

Answer (score 1):

A bit obvious, I know, but start by using `SerialPort` component from `System.IO.Ports` namespace.

Comment: Thank you Graham.  What do you do after that?

Answer (score 1):

The examples section of this: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx` MSDN page offers all the functions you require to get the serial port up, and parse in data. You'll of course need your Serial port open, set to the correct parity on the Arduino end to receive the desired data you want to send and process it - but there are more than enough examples of that.

Answer (score 0):

The examples provided by Mike should give a general layout, but as for setting up the serial port in your program you are most likely going to abide by [9600 8N1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-N-1).

Here is an example of the initial serial port settings for 9600 8N1 (These are for C++ using Boost libraries, but it should make it clear what you will need to set):

```
port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));
port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::parity(asio::serial_port_base::parity::none));
port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
```

When I set this up in the past the only thing I had to ensure was the baud rate on the Arduino matched that of the above settings, otherwise the rest seemed to be default settings. I can't guarantee this in your case though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write to serial the Arduino is connected to. Windows regards a serial as a file, so to write to the serial, use this class (I use VS2013, but it should work for VS2015 as well):

Header (named SerialClass.h):

```
#ifndef SERIALCLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define SERIALCLASS_H_INCLUDED

#define ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME 2000

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Serial
{
private:
    //Serial comm handler
    HANDLE hSerial;
    //Connection status
    bool connected;
    //Get various information about the connection
    COMSTAT status;
    //Keep track of last error
    DWORD errors;

public:
    //Initialize Serial communication with the given COM port
    Serial(char *portName);
    //Close the connection
    ~Serial();
    //Read data in a buffer, if nbChar is greater than the
    //maximum number of bytes available, it will return only the
    //bytes available. The function return -1 when nothing could
    //be read, the number of bytes actually read.
    int ReadData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar);
    //Writes data from a buffer through the Serial connection
    //return true on success.
    bool WriteData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar);
    //Check if we are actually connected
    bool IsConnected();


};

#endif // SERIALCLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

CPP file (named SerialClass.cpp):

```
#include "SerialClass.h"
#include<iostream>
Serial::Serial(char *portName)
{
    //We're not yet connected
    this->connected = false;

    //Try to connect to the given port throuh CreateFile
    this->hSerial = CreateFile(portName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    //Check if the connection was successfull
    if (this->hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //If not success full display an Error
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){

            //Print Error if neccessary
            printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available.\n", portName);

        }
        else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
        {
            printf("It is this!!!!");

        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR!!!");
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            std::cout << error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //If connected we try to set the comm parameters
        DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };

        //Try to get the current
        if (!GetCommState(this->hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
        {
            //If impossible, show an error
            printf("failed to get current serial parameters!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Define serial connection parameters for the arduino board
            dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
            dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
            dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
            //Setting the DTR to Control_Enable ensures that the Arduino is properly
            //reset upon establishing a connection
            dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

            //Set the parameters and check for their proper application
            if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
            {
                printf("ALERT: Could not set Serial Port parameters");
            }
            else
            {
                //If everything went fine we're connected
                this->connected = true;
                //Flush any remaining characters in the buffers 
                PurgeComm(this->hSerial, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
                //We wait 2s as the arduino board will be reseting
                Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
            }
        }
    }

}

Serial::~Serial()
{
    //Check if we are connected before trying to disconnect
    if (this->connected)
    {
        //We're no longer connected
        this->connected = false;
        //Close the serial handler
        CloseHandle(this->hSerial);
    }
}

int Serial::ReadData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
    //Number of bytes we'll have read
    DWORD bytesRead;
    //Number of bytes we'll really ask to read
    unsigned int toRead;

    //Use the ClearCommError function to get status info on the Serial port
    ClearCommError(this->hSerial, &this->errors, &this->status);

    //Check if there is something to read
    if (this->status.cbInQue>0)
    {
        //If there is we check if there is enough data to read the required number
        //of characters, if not we'll read only the available characters to prevent
        //locking of the application.
        if (this->status.cbInQue>nbChar)
        {
            toRead = nbChar;
        }
        else
        {
            toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
        }

        //Try to read the require number of chars, and return the number of read bytes on success
        if (ReadFile(this->hSerial, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL) && bytesRead != 0)
        {
            return bytesRead;
        }

    }

    //If nothing has been read, or that an error was detected return -1
    return -1;

}


bool Serial::WriteData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    //Try to write the buffer on the Serial port
    if (!WriteFile(this->hSerial, (void *)buffer, nbChar, &bytesSend, 0))
    {
        //In case it don't work get comm error and return false
        ClearCommError(this->hSerial, &this->errors, &this->status);

        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

bool Serial::IsConnected()
{
    //Simply return the connection status
    return this->connected;
}
```

Example of usage (writing text to the serial):

```
Serial Arduino = Serial("COM3"); //My Arduino is at COM3 - change it for yours!
if (Arduino.IsConnected() == false)  //Checks if it connected
{
    std::cout << "Your Arduino isn't connected!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 1;
}
Arduino.WriteData("This is sent data"); //Sends "This is sent data" to the Serial which Arduino is connected to!
```

The Arduino should read data from the Serial (using the Serial class).

Note that **your Arduino will have to be connected to the laptop via USB** (not Wifi) for this to work . . .

**Source:** I did a project just like this!